# How to compile WPF with .net Native

Tags: .net, wpf

I read this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/whats-new/index#whats-new-in-the-net-framework-451) that says .net framework 4.5.1 support to compile the app with .net native.

[image]

But I can't find any articles to tell me how to compile wpf with .net native.

I try open my sln in VisualStudio but I can't find any option to do it.

Can you give me some article to compile wpf with .net native.

Answer (score 3):

> I read this article that says .net framework 4.5.1 support to compile the app with .net native.

No, it doesn't. It says that "the .NET Framework content set now includes documentation for .NET Native" which is a totally different thing.

WPF and other types of "classic" desktop apps does *not* support .NET native because .NET Native applies to Universal Windows Platform (UWP) apps only. This hasn't changed and there is no .NET native support for classic desktop apps on the roadmap as far I know.

Comment: Soga, but I still find some way to improve performance. I ask this question for taking one's chance.

Comment: For .net 4.5.1 is published in 2014 and today is 2017 that I think Microsoft may use some black technology to compile the app with .net native.

Comment: All you need to do is give Microsoft more money. The more money you give, the greater chances that .NET Native will enter into WPF. This is a joke, but also a reality. WPF's input-output ratio is very small and it's the case at least for Microsoft.

Comment: "black technology to compile the app with .net native"? No. .NET native applies only to UWP.

Comment: @mm8 .Net native can apply to windows store app.

Comment: @mm8 Windows 8 app

Comment: @lindexi: That's true, but again what is your point? WPF doesn't support .NET Native and that's the answer to your question.

Comment: @mm8 I know it but I ask the question for tasking a chance.

Comment: "tasking a chance"? I don't know what that means.

Answer (score 2):

Now we can use [Microsoft.DotNet.Framework.NativeImageCompiler](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.DotNet.Framework.NativeImageCompiler) to compile the .NET Framework(>4.6.2) with native image.

See [Optimize your .NET desktop apps with native images - MSIX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-r2r)

The other way is update the project to dotnet core and then install the Microsoft.DotNet.ILCompiler nuget package which will compile to native when we publish

```
  dotnet publish -r win-x64 -c release
```